# Add directive inside other directive in directive definition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

My mind is melting while trying to nest directives into each other or to say it better: to re-use an existing directive inside the definition of another directive.

Say I have an existing HTML markup like this:

```
<a class="class1 class2" href="#link1" data-important="data1">Test</a>
```

I now want to add new functionality to this existing markup with a custom directive `myDirective`:

```
<a class="class1 class2" href="#link1" data-important="data1" my-directive>Test</a>
```

It doesn't matter what `myDirective` does, but I want to re-use the `ngClick` functionality. Normally I would replace the markup with a new template, but I don't know all classes, attributes, etc. beforehand. What I really need is a way to *append* `ngClick`. I tried something like this, but it didn't work:

```
// inside myDirective
compile: function (element, attrs) {
  element.attr('ng-click', 'customFunction()');
}
```

So I do it this way now:

```
// inside myDirective
link: function(scope, element, attrs, someCtrl) {
  element.bind('click', function() {
    someCtrl.customFunction();
    scope.$apply();
  });
}
```

This works but

- I need to call `scope.$apply();`
- It is *okay* to emulate `ngClick` in this way, but I couldn't reuse a more complex directive.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to recompile the entire element like this:

```
directive('myDirective', ['$compile', function($compile){
    return{
        compile: function (element, attrs) {
           return {
               pre: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
                  if(typeof $attrs.ngClick === "undefined"){
                      $element.attr('ng-click', 'customFunction()');
                      $compile($element)($scope);
                  }
               }
           };
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The first way you tried won't work because angular needs to compile to recognize directives. The second way you tried is pretty routine, but you should not have to use `scope.$apply()`, depending on what you're doing.

Also, setting the attribute of `ng-click` and then re-compiling would be a bit risky because someone using your directive wouldn't know that it will override an `ng-click` that they add later on. @kamilkp's answer prevents that, but then that means `customFunction` also won't fire.  It also means double-compiling your element and any directives attached to it.

If you just attach the click handler, an ng-click still works on the element in addition to `customFunction` firing.

Comment: I marked @kamilkp answers as the accepted answer, because I think it is technically the correct answer to my question. However you made some valid points against my case. So what would you recommend to do instead? Should I just stick with my `link` function?

Maybe a case for re-using `ngClick`: if I drop `ngTouch` in my project, it replaces `ngClick` with enhanced behavior. This wouldn't work with a simple `element.bind('click'`. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, it would work just fine, except on some devices there is a 300ms delay which is easy to work around.